# How to solve whole clickable div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my `Javascript`. I have a collapsible area which has content and input fields for my users to write something on. I have made a JavaScript function that collapses and opens the div, but the problem is that you can't write something on the input fields in this area, because the whole div is clickable. **I don't want the whole div to be clicakble, but only the area with the title to be clickable.**

How can I make only, and only the header, clickable?

**HTML:** 
    Test title
           blablbala

```
<div class="area">Test title
       <div class="some content">blablbala
          <input></input>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function areaCollapse() {
    var next = this.querySelector(".content");

    if (this.classList.contains("open")) {
        next.style.display = "none";
        this.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
        next.style.display = "block";
        this.classList.add("open");
    }
}

    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("area");

    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', areaCollapse, true);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1BJK903/nb1ao39k/6/

I think that I have to change the structure of my HTML. I tried this already:

Comment: `<div class="area">Test title...` modify it to become `<div class="area"><div>Test title</div>...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this fiddle if this is what you wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/nb1ao39k/5/

I added this:

```
if(this != evt.target){
    return;
}// if the element that listened to the event is not the element who was clicked then ignore
```

Comment: Best solution for me. Thank you Saar!

Comment: The problem here is that each click inside the area raise an event ! if you only listen on an inside element it is more precise and less expensive. see my answer and @AtheistP3ace answer more direct

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the event went to an input element before bubbling:

```
function areaCollapse(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, only allow clicks on the title, not the rest of the div.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I appreciate your help. Can't mark two answers as solved, otherwise I would. Upvoted though

Answer (score 1):

Working Version :

```js
function areaCollapse() {
    var next = this.parentNode.children[1];

    if (this.classList.contains("open")) {
        next.style.display = "none";
        this.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
        next.style.display = "block";
        this.classList.add("open");
    }
}
    
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
    
    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', areaCollapse, true);
    }
```

```css
.content {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="area"><div class='title'>Test title</div>
       <div class="some content">blablbala
        <input></input></div>
    </div>

<div class="area"><div class='title'>Test title</div>
       <div class="some content">blablbala
    <input></input></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I found Saar's answer a little bit better, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="area">
    <h2 class="clickable-header">Test title</h2>
       <div class="some content" style="display: none">blablbala
          <input></input>
       </div>
    </div>

<div class="area">
    <h2 class="clickable-header">Test title</h2>
       <div class="some content">blablbala
          <input></input>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function areaCollapse() {
    var next = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (this.classList.contains("open")) {
        next.style.display = "none";
        this.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
        next.style.display = "block";
        this.classList.add("open");
    }
}

    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("clickable-header");

    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', areaCollapse, true);
    }
```

Just adds a heading element which is the clickable portion.

Comment: Very nice alternative. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be clear I changed your querySelector to nextSibling since the inner div is not a child of the h2.